# Selecting Element Parent within Calling Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, zclip

I have the following jQuery which uses zClip to allow copy to clipboard. It works ok with only one selector but not with multiple. I'm trying to use $(this) to select the parent but it crashes the browser.

```
$('.copylink').zclip({
                path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
                copy: jQuery(this).parent().text()
            });
```

This is the example given on zClip [website](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#usage)

```
$('a#copy-description').zclip({
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('p#description').text()
    });
    // The link with ID "copy-description" will copy
    // the text of the paragraph with ID "description"
```

**MY HTML**

which I'm trying to use, need select the parent element text of the above html

```
<ul>
<li>the text i will like to select and pull <a href="" class="copylink">Copy</a></li>
<li>the text i will like to select and pull <a href="" class="copylink">Copy</a></li>
<li>the text i will like to select and pull <a href="" class="copylink">Copy</a></li>
<li>the text i will like to select and pull <a href="" class="copylink">Copy</a></li>
<li>the text i will like to select and pull <a href="" class="copylink">Copy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I believe my problem lies including jQuery inside a javascript object and using **this** to capture outside scope value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.each()` to apply the plugin:

```
jQuery('.copylink').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).zclip({
        path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: jQuery(this).parent().text()
    });
});
```

Now `this` will be a reference to the current `.copylink` element in the iteration.

Comment: That worked but the browser still taking forever to load the page since there are 2,000 LI elements. Unknown why.

Comment: @Codex73: Yes, I would imagine that with 2000 elements it will take some time. You may want to find  a different approach that loads not all elements at once.

Comment: The problem which is still causing the browser to crash is not the amount of list html items but the jQuery wiring it self. Something is still not right.

Comment: @Codex73: The jQuery wiring? So if you run this on 3 elements, it still crashes?

Comment: The problem is that it's trying to load path property one for each so it hangs. How could I load this once? Firebug shows the flash movie loading...

Comment: @Codex73: Then it sounds like an issue in the plugin. Can't help much there.